# Updated Ruby in production and now Rails won't start because still referencing old ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, passenger

Just updated Ruby on a staging server via RVM:

```
$ rvm upgrade 1.9.3-p327 1.9.3-p362
```

I said 'yes' to all the migration and alias questions including deleting old Ruby.

Now getting error from **Passenger** whenever I try to access Rails application:

```
Error message: 
dlopen(/Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle, 9): 
Library not loaded: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib 
Referenced from: /Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle 
Reason: image not found - /Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle
```

I've re-installed Passenger...and also ran `cap deploy` with slightly updated `Gemfile`. but it appears there are still some references to the old Ruby. **What's happening here and how can up update, or re-compile, so gems etc reference new Ruby?** Is there some flag I can specify in Capistrano that would force the recompiling of gems (assuming that's the problem)?

Edit (adding some RVM info):

I'm using a "Multi-user" installation of **RVM** on this server and because of that the gems are installed in: `/Library/WebServer/rails/popup/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems` and not where I might have expected them: `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems`. Never really understood what RVM was doing in a Multi-user installation but it has worked.

So, poing being I can't really `$ rvm gemset use myapp` and then `bundle install` because I don't think that would install in the correct directory.

Here's **Capistrano**'s output during `bundle install` task:

```
  * 2013-01-03 19:23:22 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/releases/20130104032317 && bundle install --gemfile /Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/releases/20130104032317/Gemfile --path /Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
```

Comment: Are you using apache or nginx? If apache, did you at any point have to update the module included in httpd.conf? I'm curious if the web server is trying to use a broken passenger module.

Comment: **apache**. 3 lines added to `httpd.conf` after Passenger install (as usual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is about `/Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle` referencing non existing file `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib` this should not happen as in most cases `libruby.1.9.1.dylib` should be available as already loaded from ruby when it's running. So either you have installed ruby using only static compilation or it might be broken.

Are you sure ruby `1.9.3-p362` is used? RVM provides `1.9.3-p327` for OSX 10.8 which is compiled statically (no package manager issue on OSX). Maybe you used that version(`p327`) instead?

As for reinstalling the gems - there is not yet a command that would force reinstalling installed gems in bundler, however you can just remove the gems and force installation fresh:

```
cd /Library/WebServer/rails/myapp/
rm -rf shared/bundle
bundle install
```

Comment: @mpapis- yes, `=* ruby-1.9.3-p362 [ x86_64 ]` is installed on this machine. And the upgrade process wiped out the previous version and for whatever reason, didn't update the links, though RVM upgrade process said it would. Guessing gems need to be reinstalled but see my 'Edit (adding some RVM info)' above as to why I can't just `rvm gemset use myapp` and `bundle install`. or at least i don't think i can!?!

Comment: RVM upgrades any information that it can manage, but your local bundler directory is in no way known to RVM so it can not upgrade it, that's the cost of using `bundle install --deployment` or bundler capistrano integration.

Comment: yeah, that's what I figured. So best way to repair things would be to `rm -rf shared/bundle` on the server and then `cap deploy` from the development machine again? And see where that gets me…

Comment: yeah, that's basically what my answer says ... maybe except the deploy - but that should work the same way

Comment: worked thanks! Is there a better way I should be handling this? Let me know if you (or someone else) can think of one…

Comment: read on deployment options of `bundler/capistrano` integration, it would be best if you could disable any extra flags like `--deployment` and clean `.bundle/config` - then whenever you run `rvm upgrade ...` it will have possibility to upgrade your gems.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rvm list` to list all your ruby versions

then use `rvm use <ruby version>` to use that version

Ex:

```
[sameera@sameera ~]$ rvm list

rvm rubies

     ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
=>   ruby-1.8.7-p357 [ x86_64 ]

rvm use rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

HTH

Comment: `$ rvm list` shows: `=* ruby-1.9.3-p362 [ x86_64 ]`. The RVM used is a 'system' installed RVM (or whatever they're calling it now). Don't know if that has anything to do with this?!?  Things were working fine under the previous Ruby.  I'm just trying figure out best way to upgrade Ruby in a production environment.