# Ruby, Versions, Gems, Versions and more, Oh My

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, rbenv

Apologies for the topic title, couldn't resist.

Basically, For no reason whatsoever apart from trying out different things. I want to implode RVM and try out rbenv. Nothing against RVM, just want to try different peoples software and try different things out.

I can get rid of RVM and install rbenv no problem. Could you guys confirm a few things for me.

Firstly, if I do the above, and then install a few different ruby versions. I know I can place a .ruby-version file in a projects root directory to specify a specific ruby version but then when I say `gem install <gemname>` I take it that is installed globally for that ruby version.

If I then use bundler per project to manage what gems are used and I specify a gem version, what happens if the version specified in the lock file is different to the currently installed version and what happens if it's vice versa?

I just need a bit of clarification on what's doing what in regards to ruby, versions, gems and their versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the (many) lovely things about `rbenv` is that you can so easily look right at your ruby installation to see what's going on. For example, on my machine I can open *~/.rbenv* and there's *versions* containing my ruby installations, such as *1.9.3-p327*. Opening that, I can keep drilling down to see my gems installed for that version of ruby (in *~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems*). It is then trivial to run `gem list` or `gem install somegem` and confirm that what's being affected is this very collection of gems - if this is the current ruby (set in `rbenv global` and starred in `rbenv versions`).

In short, everything about your system thinks that `ruby` means this version of ruby and that its library is this library.

For Bundler, you'll need to install `rbenv-bundler`. A nice tutorial (easily found with Google) is here: http://dan.carley.co/blog/2012/02/07/rbenv-and-bundler/

Comment: Thanks for that, so If I follow that and disallow bundler to share gems, each gem I specify in bundler is installed into a vendor directory for that project and if I use the same gem in a different project it is installed again for that one. Correct? What would happen if I allowed bunder to share?

Comment: bundler would use common rubygems directory - either default or from `GEM_HOME`/`GEM_PATH` - there are issues with using bundler default deployment options http://stackoverflow.com/a/14151386/497756

Comment: So is the config option for disabling shared gems set by default? If so then where because I don't have a .bundle directory either in my home directory or in any of my project directories.